# Data values NaN after normalization is applied and structure changes

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, data-preprocessing

I am trying to normalize my values before using the neural net function however, when normalizing my values they turn into NaN and I go from how the values are inside my dataDelay variable to a single observation with 88 variables instead of the original amount.

```
library(neuralnet)
library(grid)
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(gridExtra)
library(neuralnet)

normalize <- function(x){
  return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min (x)))
}


data <-
  structure(
    list(
      `USD/EUR` = c(
        1.373,
        1.386,
        1.3768,
        1.3718,
        1.3774,
        1.3672,
        1.3872,
        1.3932,
        1.3911,
        1.3838,
        1.4171,
        1.4164,
        1.3947,
        1.3675,
        1.3801,
        1.3744,
        1.3759,
        1.3743,
        1.3787,
        1.3595,
        1.3599,
        1.3624,
        1.3523,
        1.3506,
        1.3521
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-25L),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame")
  )


#time series delay
dataDelay <- embed(data[[1]], 4)[, 4:1]
#normalizing values
currencyNorm <- as.data.frame(lapply(dataDelay, normalize))

Input <- subset(dataDelay, select = c(dataDelay[1], dataDelay[2], dataDelay[3]))
Output <- subset(dataDelay, select = c(dataDelay[4]))

##NN model
currency_model <- neuralnet(Output~Input, hidden = 1, data = dataDelay)
```

dataDelay output:

```
      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
[1,] 1.3730 1.3860 1.3768 1.3718
[2,] 1.3860 1.3768 1.3718 1.3774
[3,] 1.3768 1.3718 1.3774 1.3672
[4,] 1.3718 1.3774 1.3672 1.3872
[5,] 1.3774 1.3672 1.3872 1.3932
[6,] 1.3672 1.3872 1.3932 1.3911
```

After normalizing:

```
NaN. NaN..1 NaN..2 NaN..3 NaN..4 NaN..5 NaN..6 NaN..7 NaN..8 NaN..9 NaN..10 NaN..11 NaN..12
1  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN...
```

Applying to full dataset:

```
normalize <- function(x){
  return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min (x)))
}


exchangeData <- read.csv("ExchangeUSDcsv.csv")
data <- exchangeData[,3]
data <- as.data.frame(data)

currencyNorm <- embed(normalize(data[[1]]), 4)[, 4:1]
head(currencyNorm)

currencyNorm <- as.data.frame(currencyNorm)
```

[ PROBLEM AFTER APPLYING SOLUTION CODE ON FULL DATASET ]

Full dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/17exy1968lsidsc/ExchangeUSDcsv.csv?dl=0

Output when applied to full dataset:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: Do you want to normalize by column? Or the data as a whole?

Comment: The data as a whole

Comment: Try `normalize(c(dataDelay))`. One of the side effects of `c()` is to remove all attributes except for `names`.

Comment: Only problem I get when doing it like this is that it breaks the original format of the data in dataDelay. Is there a way to keep it in the same format too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do column wise normalisation of matrix use `apply` :

```
currencyNorm <- data.frame(apply(dataDelay, 2, normalize))
```

To normalize complete data as whole :

```
currencyNorm <- normalize(dataDelay)
```

Comment: Ah okay. What does the 2 mean?

Comment: It should be `normalize(c(dataDelay))`.

Comment: @ASH It means by column, dim 2.

Comment: Ah okay. So If I wanted to normalize the dataset as a whole for input to a neural network, I would do it like this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the simplest way is to normalize from the original `data`.

```
currencyNorm <- embed(normalize(data[[1]]), 4)[, 4:1]
```

---

But if this is a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) then maybe the following code is more to the point.
It builds a neural net from `currencyNorm` with one hidden layer. To extract the subsets `Input` and `Output` is not needed, the formula `V4 ~ .` models the 4th column `V4` on all other columns.

```
library(neuralnet)

currencyNorm <- embed(normalize(data[[1]]), 4)[, 4:1]
currencyNorm <- as.data.frame(currencyNorm)
##NN model
currency_model <- neuralnet(V4 ~ ., hidden = 1, data = currencyNorm)
```

In order to predict with the model, you will have to have 3 values, one for each of `V1`, `V2` and `V3`.

```
set.seed(2021)   # make the results reproducible
new <- data.frame(V1 = runif(1), V2 = runif(1), V3 = runif(1))

predict(currency_model, newdata = new)
#          [,1]
#[1,] 0.6168927
```

Or a new data set with many rows.

```
new2 <- data.frame(V1 = runif(5), V2 = runif(5), V3 = runif(5))
predict(currency_model, newdata = new2)
```

Comment: Oh right this is awesome! The goal for the neural network is to know the first 3 values and then to predict the fourth. Is this what you code does above?

Comment: This was working well with my smaller sample data on here but when I apply it to the full dataset I get the same NA problem. I have edited the post to show my code and result when I apply your code on my dataset. I have also provided the full dataset file. Would you mind giving it a look?